# How to execute all commands stored as strings in a table in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Long story short I'm generating a table with commands and then I'm executing them in another window; I want to automate this part but I have no clue how to do it.

Example of values in the table (`select * from tmp_cmd`):

- USE DB1 EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.Split'
- USE DB2 EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.Split'
- USE DB2 EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.neutralSplit'

How can I execute every command from that table?

Comment: *"im generating a table with commands"* This is honestly a really bad idea. Storing statements in a table often leads to injection and the "need" to store such statements is normally a large indicator a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Also, why do you want to recompile all these objects?

Comment: I think you want `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = (SELECT STRING_AGG(cmd, ';') FROM dbo.tmp_cmd);EXEC(@SQL);`

Comment: In the simplest way, that would certainly work, @DanGuzman . I wonder what the OP is after in the event that one statement fails. Should the other latter statements still be executed?  Should the prior be rolled back?

Comment: For starters, `STRING_SPLIT` is available in all mainstream versions of SQL Server (ie 2016+). For earlier versions, the typical string splitting techniques **don't** require recompilation. Only catch-all queries require recompilation *every time they are called* to avoid reusing bad execution plans. Manual recompilation won't help at all - the execution plan will be cached the first time the stored procedure is called.

Comment: @Larnu, true, there are unspecified details in the question. The example in my comment  will continue unless there is an error parsing error or a batch-terminating run-time error.  It would be sufficient for the `sp_recompile` but maybe not more complex cases.

Comment: @Larnu I got an information that we need to recompile said storeprocedures to fix other issues, ive been doing it by hand but its a pain and i wanted to automate it. the content of what need to recompiled is generated earlier in the script (we got that from our dev team as well) i thought i will be able to automate it on my own.

Comment: @DanGuzman i will try that in a few and let you know id it helped

Comment: @DanGuzman i cant seem to use STRING_AGG its not recognised, i will need to look into it and see why

Comment: `STRING_AGG` was introduced in SQL Server 2017 so it seems you're using an older version (good practice to add the version-specific tag to SQL Server questions). See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380) for the XML method for aggregate string concatenation you can use in older versions.

Comment: I would just write a cursor for this. I don't know how many commands you have in your table, but it can't be that many. This isn't a setbased task anyway, you don't have to execute them all in one go. A cursor also provides room for error handling. This is supposing its a good idea, I agree with Larnu; this is a suspicious solution (I have done it myself on numerous occasions though).